# using a serial connection and using command screen causes the login text to scroll by rapidly multiple times

Tags: raspbian, pi-b

I'm trying to connect to my raspberry pi through a USB to TTL cable, however, when I use:

```
 sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

It results in a console that is rapidly scrolling with the login message, any idea what's the cause of this?

I use a Pi B with a fresh installation of Raspbian (downloaded 2 hours ago)

Comment: Does it finish with scrolling if you do nothing? If so, what happens if you just hit *return* then?

Answer (score -1):

Connected it to a different USB port and now it works...

Comment: Just pull out and plug in to the same USB port may also help. It resets the  USB to TTL converter in the cable plug.